# R : know table(s), how to calc quantile(s)

Tags: r, quantile

s is a large array, just save table(s) in database

```
> table_s
s
1       2 3  4                   5
3000000 1 1  999999999999999999  34
```

how to calc quantile(s) with table_s in R ?

thanks

Comment: type `?quantile` into the R console

Comment: @timriffe There is no `quantile` function for class `table`, and `rep` is unsuitable for such large `times` arguments.  Not sure how `?quantile` is of help here.

Comment: oops, quantile doesn't have weights, but Hmisc::wtd.quantile() does. will answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the quantile function from the Hmisc package, which allows weights.

```
Hmisc::wtd.quantile(as.numeric(names(table_s)),weights = table_s)
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest (but computationally expensive) way I can think of is to re-expand your table into a vector of observations and use the `quantile` function:

```
s <- c(3000000,1,1,999999999999999999,34)
names(s) <- 1:5    
quantile(rep.int(as.integer(names(s)),times=s))
#  0%  25%  50%  75% 100% 
#   1    4    4    4    5
```

If you are looking for something faster, then you might need to write your own function.

EDIT: As Matthew Lundberg states in the comments, the code above doesn't work. It will run only if `sum(s)` is less than the maximum possible length of a vector, which is currently 2^31-1 < 10^10.

Comment: 2.15.2 does not like that code: `Error in rep.int(as.integer(names(s)), times = s) : invalid 'times' value
In addition: Warning message:
In rep.int(as.integer(names(s)), times = s) : NAs introduced by coercion`

Comment: Whoops, you're right. I think this does work up as long as the resulting vector is less than the maximum length of a vector in R: 2^31-1, which is less than 10^10.